# Cassandra PHP All connections on all I/O threads are busy

Tags: php, cassandra

I have a problem with getting results from cassandra through PHP. The error comes randomly (sometimes after 30 reloads, sometimes few times in a row). I'm using DataStax PHP Driver 1.30 and PHP 7.0.

The Error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>       Type: Cassandra\Exception\RuntimeException
>       Message: All connections on all I/O threads are busy

My connection constructor:

```
$this->cluster  = Cassandra::cluster()
    >withContactPoints('172.16.0.31')
    ->build();
$this->session  = $this->cluster->connect($this->keyspace);
```

My get table function:

```
$sql = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
$future = $this->session->executeAsync($sql);
$result = $future->get();
return $result;
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The keyspace that you connected is exist ??

Comment: Have you tried enabling persistent sessions?
`Cassandra::cluster()->withPersistentSessions(true)` along with your other cluster build options.

Answer (score 0):

Y, keyspace exist
i fount a solution:
the connection constructor should be:`$this->cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
->withContactPoints('172.16.0.31')->withIOThreads(5)->build();
$this->session  = $this->cluster->connect($this->keyspace);`